Parametric differential equations
I'm totally beginner in Wolfram. And I trying to do some research. If it's not difficult for you, please help me.
I have a system of three differential equations with four parameters: beta, delta, p, c.
When I know these four parameters, I can solve this system, and I can draw graphs of solutions.
It looks like this:
beta = 1.59*10^-8;
delta = 10^-6;
p = 23.91;
c = 10^-8;

system1 = {
  u'[t] == -beta*u[t]*v[t],
  i'[t] == beta*u[t]*v[t] - delta*i[t],
  v'[t] == p*i[t] - c*v[t]
};

initials = {
u[0] == 70000, i[0] == 0, v[0] == 7000};

nds = NDSolve[{system1, initials}, {u[t], i[t], v[t]}, {t, 0, 10000}];
Plot[{u[t]} /. nds, {t, 0, 10000}, PlotRange -> All]
Plot[{i[t]} /. nds, {t, 0, 100}, PlotRange -> All]
Plot[{v[t]} /. nds, {t, 0, 100}, PlotRange -> All]

It all works amazing!
But now I want to manipulate all these four parameters. And depending on their values, draw graphs of solutions.
I tried to do this at least for the beta parameter using the functions ParametricNDSolve, Manipulate, Plot. But I have a lot of problems.
delta = 10^-6;
p = 23.91;
c = 10^-8;

system1 = {
   u'[t] == -beta*u[t]*v[t],
   i'[t] == beta*u[t]*v[t] - delta*i[t],
   v'[t] == p*i[t] - c*v[t]
};

initials = {
   u[0] == 70000, i[0] == 0, v[0] == 7000};

nds = ParametricNDSolve[{system1, initials}, {u[t], i[t], v[t]}, {t, 
   0, 10000}, beta];
Manipulate[Plot[{u[t]} /. nds, {t, 0, 10000}, PlotRange -> All], {beta, 
   1*10^-8, 2*10^-8}]


Thank you in advance for any help!!!

Try this: Manipulate[  nds = NDSolve[{system1, initials} /. beta -> b, {u[t], i[t], v[t]}, {t, 0, 100}];  Plot[{u[t]} /. nds, {t, 0, 100}, PlotRange -> All],  {b, 1*10^-8, 5*10^-8}]

Mathematica 's Manipulate doesn't know parameter dependency t,beta of solution nds
Try
delta = 10^-6;
p = 23.91;
c = 10^-8;

system1 = {u'[t] == -beta*u[t]*v[t], 
i'[t] == beta*u[t]*v[t] - delta*i[t], v'[t] == p*i[t] - c*v[t]};

initials = {u[0] == 70000, i[0] == 0, v[0] == 7000};

uiv = ParametricNDSolveValue[{system1, initials}, {u , i , v }, {t, 0,
10000}, beta] 
Manipulate[
Plot[uiv [beta][[1]][t], {t, 0, 10000}, PlotRange -> All], {beta,1*10^-8, 2*10^-8}]



Thank you so much, Ulrich! That's what I need
